# Views 8.x fields collection relationship

Tags: 8, entities, views

In D7 views it was very easy to get to a particular field from field collection - by relationship.

How about now? I can not see any relationship connected with this collection. I am able to display FC content only (all at once, by one field).

Any ideas?